# mux router returns error 503 on debian stretch (linux), works on Windows 10

Tags: go

I'm having a weird issue on a Linux server, when I run my app and navigate to it, it gives me error 503 service unavailable.

I'm using the mux router and it works perfectly fine on Windows, but on Linux for some reason it does not.

I have routes passed to a middleware where a handler is done, like so...

**middleware.go**

```
func SetRoute(r *mux.Router, uri string, handle func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request), methods string) {
    r.HandleFunc(uri, handle).Methods(methods)
    r.Use(MiddlewareHandle)
}

func MiddlewareHandle(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        start := time.Now()

        defer func() {
            log.Println(r.URL.Path, time.Since(start))
        }()

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Then for my routes:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()

middleware.SetRoute(r, "/", index.Index, "GET")

srv := &http.Server{
    Handler:      r,
    Addr:         "127.0.0.1:8080",
    WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
    ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
}

log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
```

And my handle would be this:

```
type IndexData struct {
    PageTitle   string
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := IndexData{
        PageTitle:   "Hello World",
    }

    err := template.Must(template.New(BaseTemplate).Funcs(FuncTemplate).ParseFiles(BaseTemplate, "index.html")).ExecuteTemplate(w, "skeleton", data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Any idea why it's not working on Linux (Debian Stretch) ?

Comment: Please include all code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: See [How to Create a Minimal, Verifiable and Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Adrian updated.